# How to get getRequestUri() in layout.phtml

Tags: html, zend-framework

In my zend layout.phtml I am serving my navigation like this:

```
<?php                                  
    $userInfo = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userInfo');             
    if($userInfo->userType=='admin')
    {   
        echo '<li ><a href="/adminhome">home</a></li>';
        echo '<li ><a href="addbook">Addbooks</a></li>';
        echo '<li class="selected"><a href="about.html">EditBook</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="logout">Adduser</a></li>';               
        echo '<li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

in a normal page I can get url this way

```
$this->view->assign('url',$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
$url = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
$b=basename($url);     
$this->view->assign('b',$b);
```

I want this url in my layout.phtm how can I pass this from bootstrap.php to layout.phtml? here my requirement is to add a class to li like this:

```
 <li    <?php if($b==EditBook) echo 'class="selected'  ?> "><a href="about.html">EditBook</a></li>
```

Comment: serving what navigation , LOL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to obtain it, is to write a view helper that will assign necessary variables

```
class Helper_Params extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
    $view = $this->getActionController()->view;
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $view->requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
}
```

and init it in your Bootstrap

```
public function _initHelpers() {
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper ( new Helper_Params () );
}
```